# Plotting in logit (regession)

Tags: regression, logistic, data-visualization

I'm trying to do something a little funny here with a logistic regression. I have a binary outcome, a time variable, and some confounders. I wanted to plot the monthly mean of the outcome in logit and put the regression line on top of it but the estimates seem too far off from the data. I'm sure it's something super bonehaded but lemme know what you think.

Here's a simplified version of my problem:

```
set.seed(0)
library('tidyverse')

# fake data:
outcome = (1:100)/300
outcome = lapply(X = outcome, 
                 FUN = function(x){sample(x = 0:1, 
                                                       size = 100, 
                                                       replace = TRUE, 
                                                       prob = c(x, 1-x))}) %>% 
  unlist
test_set = tibble(outcome = outcome,
                  month = rep(1:100, each = 100),
                  v1 = rnorm(n = 10000),
                  v2 = rnorm(n = 10000),
                  v3 = rnorm(n = 10000),
                  v4 = rnorm(n = 10000),
                  v5 = rnorm(n = 10000),
                  v6 = rnorm(n = 10000))
mod_bin = glm(formula = outcome ~ month + v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5 + v6, 
                   family = 'binomial', 
                   data = test_set)

# now compute the mean adjustment:
adj = test_set %>% 
  summarize_at(.vars = vars(matches('v[0-9]')), mean) %>% 
  gather(key = var, value = val)
adj = tibble(est = coefficients(mod_bin)[3:8],
             var = names(coefficients(mod_bin)[3:8])) %>% 
  right_join(adj)

slide = sum(adj$est*adj$val)

# Now compute the mean value and go logit
test_set %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  summarize(month_mean = mean(outcome)) %>% 
  mutate(month_mean_logit = month_mean/(1-month_mean)) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x = month, y = month_mean_logit)) +
  geom_abline(data = NULL,
              aes(intercept = coefficients(mod_bin)['(Intercept)'] + slide,
                  slope = coefficients(mod_bin)['month']))
```

[image: Plot]

Why is the regression line underneath all of the points? My understanding is that we're modeling the log odds of the outcome variable as a linear combination of the predictors. It seems like it should be somewhat close to the monthly average?

Comment: Read the help for `?predict.glm`.

Comment: Just curious about how you have generated the outcome variable - Why not using rbinom() instead of samp()?

Comment: @Umka It's not different

Comment: @whuber That's a little to cryptic for me. What did you mean by that?

Comment: First, the help makes it clear that several different things can be predicted: the link or the predicted values.  I suspect therein lies your problem.  Second, this function will do the job for you.  Third, if you still want to code the predictions yourself, it will provide the correct values for comparison.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the response. I'm aware that I can get predictions from predict.glm in logit or backtransformed. That's not what I'm trying to do. My goal was to be able to plot the regression line, in logit, using the regression coefficients.The values plotted were not predictions, they were simply averaged values over time period. I believe that these values should somewhat match the regression line as the regression is also modeling the mean value.